# Install windows updates on Azure Virtual Machine W10

Tags: azure, windows-10, virtual-machine

I have a Windows10 Azure Virtual Machine running, and via the Windows Update Config screen (in Windows) I see several updates ready to install. However, the Update and Restart option in the start menu doesn't seem to do anything, and the same for the Restart functionality in the Virtual Machine pane of Azure.

I created an Update Management schedule (via Guest & Host Update menu), but this also doesn't seem to do anything. It succeeds after one minute, and when I look on the VM it still lists the updates as needed to install.

How can I install these updates on a Windows10 Azure Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the steps in this article to clear the Windows Update Cache. Then attempt installing one at a time

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/windows-update-issues-clear-windows-update-cache/

If that fails, please try the following :

1. Click on Start, and then click Run.
2. Type cmd in the Open box to get a DOS prompt.
3. Type "net stop wuauserv" without the quotes at the command prompt, and press
   Enter.
4. Delete (or put in recycle bin) the contents of
   C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution (but not the SoftwareDistribution folder)
5. Type net start wuauserv at the command prompt, and press Enter.
6. Now try Windows Update again.

If the issue still persists, kindly share the screenshot of the windowsupdate

Also is this the only VM where the issue is happening?